# Libreoffice base - "The driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' could not be loaded" occurs even after adding class path

Tags: mysql, jdbc, libreoffice-base

I am trying to connect Libreoffice base to an already existing database. To do so, I have done the following:

1)[image: Select database]

2) I chose the "Connect using JDBC" option, and provided the database name and server. On testing class, it shows that the driver class has been loaded successfully.
[image: Setup jdbc]

3) I provided the user name and password and tested the connection, which gave me the following,

[image: authentication]

I am getting this error even though I provided the path to the .jar's. I have tried to restart libreoffice and also checked mysql.jar, for the jdbc driver (which was present) using the archive manager.
[image: class path provided]

I tried referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102600/libreoffice-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-cannot-be-loaded) at first,but the error still remained. How do I get rid of this error and establish the connection to the database ?

Comment: Why do you have three different versions of the MySQL driver on your classpath? Make sure you only use one. Also I'd be suspicious of the fact that you are using a JRE by "Free Software Foundation, Inc", version 1.5.0. Select the Java 1.8 by Oracle instead.

Comment: Oh ! It worked when I selected Oracle. Thank you. But, may I know how does this work ?

Comment: What is "this" in _"how does this work"_? The FSF implementation isn't fully Java compatible, and having multiple jars of the same driver can lead to conflicts.

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thank you :) .

Comment: In linux you can open up the connector jar with your archive manager (file-roller) and see if the path to the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class is in it.  For example, in my sys it's:  file-roller /usr/share/java/mariadb-java-client-1.5.7.jar.  Also check the file permissions of it.  Mine is set to my user (not root) ownership w/ rw permissions.